# How to center a tree diagram in D3.js using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, flexbox

I am using D3.js to make a hierarchical tree diagram. But I cannot seem to figure out how to set the `x` and `y` of the tree in the manner I want. Currently as the image below shows it shoots off vertically.

**Edit:**

It works on my monitor with a screen of 27' but on my 13' laptop it looks like this

I am using this [example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/tidy-tree) to try and get it to look the same.

```
#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 50px 150px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a JSFiddle with a complete example?

Comment: Well it is a CSS issue. I tried it on a bigger screen and it works just need to edit it to fit my screen as there is roughly 60 nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a mistake on my half assuming it was not an issue with the CSS.

I am not too familiar with CSS but the following fix of altering the padding from `padding: 0 50px 150px` to `padding: 400px 50px` worked.